# Verify Kotlin function as parameter in unittest

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am trying to verify kotlin function in parameter in unit test but failed. Here is my code

Unit test:

```
verify(moveToNextStepUseCase).execute(validateStepAssemblyUseCase.validate(ID),
                { view.showCompleteAssemblyConfirmDialog(type) },
                { view.showCompleteAssemblyErrorDialog() })
```

My `moveToNextStepUseCase` code:

```
interface MoveToNextStepUseCase {
    fun execute(validator: () -> Observable<Boolean>, successAction: () -> Unit, errorAction: () -> Unit)
}
```

My calling code:

```
moveToNextStepUseCase.execute(
                                        validateStepAssemblyUseCase.validateMissingAssembly(assignmentId),
                                        { view.showCompleteAssemblyConfirmDialog(currentStepId) },
                                        { view.showCompleteAssemblyErrorDialog() }
                                )
```

But I got the error after running test:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
moveToNextStepUseCase.execute(
    Function0<io.reactivex.Observable<java.lang.Boolean>>,
    (move next assembly step incomplete case$1) Function0<kotlin.Unit>,
    (move next assembly step incomplete case$2) Function0<kotlin.Unit>
);

Actual invocation has different arguments:
moveToNextStepUseCase.execute(
    Function0<io.reactivex.Observable<java.lang.Boolean>>,
    () Function0<kotlin.Unit>,
    () Function0<kotlin.Unit>
);
```

Anyone knows why the parameter is empty in actual invoke? `()`

Comment: You could use something like this: `any<() -> Unit>()` instead of specifying the methods directly

Comment: Yes I can use `any()`, but wonder if I can specify it directly since it's a verify

Comment: Does `verify(moveToNextStepUseCase).execute(any<() -> Observable<Boolean>(), any<() -> Unit>(), any<() -> Unit>())` work?

Comment: I have not tried that yet, what works for me is `verify(moveToNextStepUseCase).execute(any(), any(), any())`

Comment: I guess that works too, as the arguments are automatically inferred